# If 1 appears, all subsequent elements of the variable must be 1, grouped by subject

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

I want make from:

```
test <- data.frame(subject=c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10)),x=1:10,y=0:1)
```

[image: Start]

Something like that:

[image: Output]

As I wrote in the title, when the first 1 appears all subsequent values of "y" for a given "subject" must change to 1, then the same for the next "subject"

I tried something like that:

```
test <- test%>% 
  group_nest(subject) %>%
  mutate(XD = map(data,function(x){
   ifelse(x$y[which(grepl(1, x$y))[1]:nrow(x)]==TRUE , 1,0)})) %>% unnest(cols = c(data,XD))
```

It didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
new <- test %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  mutate(y=ifelse(row_number()<min(which(y==1)),y,1))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 3
# Groups:   subject [2]
   subject     x     y
     <dbl> <int> <dbl>
 1       1     1     0
 2       1     2     1
 3       1     3     1
 4       1     4     1
 5       1     5     1
 6       1     6     1
 7       1     7     1
 8       1     8     1
 9       1     9     1
10       1    10     1
11       2     1     0
12       2     2     1
13       2     3     1
14       2     4     1
15       2     5     1
16       2     6     1
17       2     7     1
18       2     8     1
19       2     9     1
20       2    10     1
```

Comment: @chrisAR Always a pleasure helping you!

Comment: @chrisAR Both of them work. Basically, it looks for the position for the first 1 and then compare with the number of row. After that the filling is done. Those values less than min will mantain the original y whereas the others will be one. Hope that is clear for you and helpful!

Comment: @chrisAR - the index value for the first `1` is already set to `1`, so you can set `<=` or `<` and it should work regardless.

Comment: @chrisAR Feel free to re accept this answer if this is helpful for you. Kind regards!

Comment: Forgive me, but the second way, even though you were the first one, seemed easier to me, but now that I've understood how it works, I gives you back "Accept Answer" :D

Answer (score 1):

Since you appear to just have 0's and 1's, a straightforward approach would be to take a `cum`ulative `max`imum via the `cummax` function:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
    group_by(subject) %>%
    mutate(y = cummax(y))
```

@Duck's answer is considerably more robust if you have a range of values that may appear before or after the first 1.

Comment: Thanks, it is much easier than i thought :D